# Number of iterations for Newton Method

Tags: numerical-methods

If I wanted to find the least number of iterations it would take for applying Newton's method on a function, is there a formula that I can use to obtain it? If so, what is that formula?

Comment: You would need to state what the result is you want to achieve. In general Newton's method will not reach a root in finitely many steps. Outside the basins of quadratic convergence the Newton iteration will mostly behave chaotically, see Newton-fractals. These basins are only large for functions with only a few roots and in low dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I know is an asymptotic bound: a quadratic rate of convergence. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: URLs with certain characters in them don't get treated well on StackExchange pages. I've patched this up to have the effect that I think you intended; please roll back or edit further if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for doing this.  Looks good, and I've learned how to typeset URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the geometry of the root. You can assume quadratic convergence as long as it is not a multiple root, ie, $f'(r)\neq0$. With high multiplicities or very small derivatives in the root Newton's method gets stuck, but can be modified to remain quadratic.